# How to assign multiple python dictionaries between modules

Tags: python, dictionary, scripting

I am trying to use a module function to initialize several dictionaries that are used as variables by subsequent modules/scripts.

Within the same directory (1) I have fname.py defining said function:

```
def Study():
    study = {'name': 'SHIVA', 'meg': '/media/ALAYA/data/ilabs/shiva/meg/',
             'subjects_dir': '/media/ALAYA/data/freesurfer/'}
    acquisition = {'nblocks': 2, 'stim_chan': 'STI101'}
    options = {'psdfqs': [1, 100], 'psd_samples': [0, 60], 'nfft': 2048}

    return study, acquisition, options
```

(2) In a second python module/script f2name.py I have made several attempts to call fname.Study(). Working one-level above the parent directory containing fname.py & f2name.py I am trying:

```
from parentdir import fname

a, b, c = fname.Study()
```

> generates AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Study'

```
a,b,c = fname()
```

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

**doh! Never mind, it was due to God damned PATH issue between environment and pycharm IDE**

Comment: What happens when you print `fname.__file__`?

Comment: fname.__file__ returns the /absolute/path/to/fname

Comment: It's the path to the correct fname? the one with Study defined in it?

Comment: yes it's the right Path, only fname.pyc rather than fname.py is returned.

Comment: It's possible the pyc is old and for some reason not updating. Delete it and run the code again.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I can find, but I'm not 100% sure these are what you're asking about:

---

```
from parentdir import fname.py
```

Should just be

```
from parentdir import fname
```

---

And unless I'm mistaken...

```
a, b, c = SHIVA_params.Study()
```

Should be

```
a, b, c = fname.Study()
```

Comment: sorry about the typos in the post, I have edited my question to accurately represent what I am trying to do; the errors you noted were my copy & paste frustrations. Question still stands.